# Why Delphi can't find & character within SQLite Select statement?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, select

Does anybody have any idea why Delphi 10.4 or 11.1 can't search for the `&` character within an SQLite `SELECT` statement in an FMX application? It's being treated like a space character.

I did try the same DB with other platforms, and it works fine, but it doesn't search even in a VCL application either.

I did try using ESCAPE at the end of the query, but nothing changed.

```
var myQuery      : TFDQuery   ;

myQuery :=TFDQuery.Create(nil);
myQuery.Connection:=FDConnection1;
myQuery.SQL.Text :='SELECT Description,Code,Qty FROM Products WHERE Description LIKE "%J&B%" ';
myQuery.Open;
```

Please help if anyone can find a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **&** has special treatment in FireDAC as can be seen in the documentation:
[Substitution Variables](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Substitution_Variables)

To avoid that, set *MacroCreate* and *MacroExpand* in *ResourceOptions* to False.